# TYPO3 8.7.12: Multiple frontend users with same username and group but in different sysfolders

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-8.x

Is it possible to have several Frontend Users with the same group and the same username, but in different sys folders? 
For example: user1 in sysfolder1 and user1 in sysfolder2.
Then I want to habe 2 Login Masks, one for users in sysfolder1 and one for sysfolder2.

Comment: Yes It possible, please check : https://prnt.sc/n5va4t , https://prnt.sc/n5va4t

Comment: can you tell me how to define the storagepid for the login process. I think the method $tsfe->fe_user->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $user->getUsername())  at my code fetches the wrong user.

Comment: If you use different page or content element login form then you can set from here : https://prnt.sc/n5vghg

Comment: okay thats not working at my case because I'm using an own login mask and $tsfe->fe_user->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $user->getUsername()) to get the userdata

Answer (score 1):

I found it out what to do, but thanks anyway

```
$userdata = $tsfe->fe_user->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $user->getUsername(), 'AND pid IN (' . (\implode(',', $this->frontendUserRepository->createQuery()->getQuerySettings()->getStoragePageIds())) . ')');
```

The third parameter 'andwhere'